# Force Activity to start off BroadcastReceiver even if phone is locked

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

At 7:51 AM, my phone executes this code to start Skype (I have Skype set to Auto-Log me in, so it essentially logs me in to skype at 7:51 AM):

```
public class MorningReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver { 
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("MorningReceiver", "Entered");

        PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        Intent skype = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.skype.raider");
        context.startActivity(skype);
    }
}
```

This used to work 100% of the time. I would be sleeping, and my phone would log me into Skype at 7:51 AM every day. However over the months I must have changed a setting or something in my phone, and now it seems to freeze on "context.startActivity(skype);" and wait for me to swipe down my lock screen, because now if I wake up at 10:00am, grab my phone and swipe down the lock screen, Skype immediately is started and logs me in -- and it had not been started and logged in at 7:51 AM as I wanted it to.

I am wondering if there is a way to force start the activity so it doesn't have to wait for any user interaction, and starts the application while my phone is locked beside me while I'm sleeping.

Just an FYI: I do not have a passcode on my phone.

Also, if needed, this is how I send the Broadcast (MorningReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver)

```
//set a Calendar object to 7:51 AM (not shown here)
//use an alarm manager to trigger the 7:51 AM event
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

//send the broadcast
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MorningReceiver.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

//repeat this every day
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```

Thanks for any help!